# Aruba virtual controller settings such as country code and virtual controller ip are not persisted after Aruba master WAP reboot

Tags: wap

I have **3 waps** in a **cluster**, **one** acting as a **master** virtual controller and the remaining **two** as **slaves**.

```
Aruba WAP 1: 200.20.200.238 (Master)
Aruba WAP 2: 200.20.200.239 (Slave)
Aruba WAP 3: 200.20.200.240 (Slave)
```

(i) I am updating the virtual-controller-country from the US to CA and the virtual controller IP as 200.20.200.240 from the 200.20.200.238 (Master Aruba WAP). Then rebooting all the slave waps from the master Aruba wap using the command reload all.

```
root@200.20.200.238's password:

WAP# show election statistics
State        : Master


WAP# configure terminal
We now support CLI commit model, please type "commit apply" for configuration to take effect.
WAP (config) # virtual-controller-ip 200.20.200.240
WAP (config) # virtual-controller-country CA
WAP (config) # end
WAP# commit apply
committing configuration...
configuration committed.
WAP# write memory
Save configuration.


WAP# show running-config
version 8.3.0.0-8.3.0
virtual-controller-country CA
virtual-controller-ip 200.20.200.240

WAP# reload all
Do you really want to reset the system (y/n): y
```

(ii) Now the new (virtual controller) **master wap** is  **200.20.200.240** . Now configuration applied to virtual-controller-country is reverted back to **US** from **CA** and the newly inserted parameter,**virtual-controller-ip** is **not available.**

```
[root@ACPU.AAL.0NG7 ~]# ssh 200.20.200.240

WAP# show election statistics
State        : Master

WAP# show running-config
version 8.3.0.0-8.3.0
virtual-controller-country US
```

Here how to make the virtual controller settings configuration persistent after Aruba WAP's reboot.

I am using Aruba 8.3 image.

**Reference:** ArubaInstant 8.3 Command-Line Interface Reference Guide - **Page numbers(768,767)** (https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00047551en_us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a cluster of 3 APs, you need 4 IP addresses. 3 (preferred DHCP) for each AP and a virtual-controller-ip that is automatically active on the master.

The master will take that IP in addition to the one it received from DHCP and you can always connect to the controller IP to reach the actual master.

For example, 200.20.200.238 is the current master and we are specifying virtual-controller-ip as 200.20.200.237 .
When we SSH to 200.20.200.237, it checks for master wap and we can reach the actual master with this Virtual controller IP.

```
[root@ACPU.DAL.02KU3 ~]# ssh 200.20.200.238
WAP# show election statistics
State : Master

WAP# configure terminal
We now support CLI commit model, please type "commit apply" for configuration to take effect.
WAP (config) # virtual-controller-ip 200.20.200.237
WAP (config) # end
WAP# commit apply
committing configuration...
configuration committed.
WAP# reload all
Do you really want to reset the system (y/n): y

[root@ACPU.DAL.02KU3 ~]# ssh 200.20.200.237
WAP# show ip interface
Interface IP Address / IP Netmask Admin Protocol
br0 200.20.200.238 / 255.255.255.0 up up
WAP# show election statistics
State : Master
```